# XmlUnit order based on value

Tags: java, xml, xpath, junit, xmlunit

I am comparing a saved example xml with a live marshalled xml in my JUnit testing. Validating the presence of a key value pair in the xml.

I am making use of [XmlUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/) 2.1.0 specifically

My xml is as follows:

```
<entries>
        <entry>
            <key>delete</key>
            <value>ENABLED</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>view</key>
            <value>DISABLED</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>create</key>
            <value>DISABLED</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
```

The order of the entries can vary. I'm unsure how to get it to validate correctly since it sees a different key value as a difference in the xml even though it's just an order change.

I am asserting similarity with the follow assertion in JUnit:

```
 assertThat(marshalledXml, isSimilarTo(Input.fromFile("path/to/example.xml").ignoreWhitespace().ignoreComments());
```

I suspect I may need to make use of XPath matchers or the DefaultNodeMatchers with an ElementSelector.

Comment: You need to override the element qualifier (see the second answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540318/compare-two-xml-strings-ignoring-element-order)

Comment: The other question is about XMLUnit 1.x, this one explicitily asks for XMLUnit 2.x which has a different API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide an `ElementSelector` that "knows" which nodes to pick for comparison in your specific case.

For most of the document the name of the element seems to be what you should use. At least that's true for `entries`, `key` and `value`. For `entry` elements you want to compare those elements, that have matching nested text in the `key` element that is their immediate child, right?

I think this translates to

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("entry")
    .thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./key", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

See https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes for a more detailed discussion of the `ElementSelector` options. Your XML is pretty close to the `table` example used in the introduction and discussed in the next sections.