# XMLUnit to ignore element order

Tags: java, xml, comparison, xmlunit-2

I want XMLUnit to ignore order when comparing. Is there a way to control that?
Eg:

```
parameter1
value1


parameter2 
value 2
```

if compared with

```
parameter2
value2

parameter1
value1
```

should not return any differences.

I am using XMLUnit 2 with Java.
I found a couple of similar questions here but none had a definite solution.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hope this link can help you [Ignore element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540318/compare-two-xml-strings-ignoring-element-order)

Comment: I tried that solution. It works perfect for the examples given there (small simple xmls) but not big complicated files which I am working on.

Comment: Would you mind showing the sample code  / data that you tried and not working?

Comment: Did you ever find anything?