Check XML files for equality ignoring element order
Consider the following xml contents:
var xml1 = """
      <root>
          <elem1>
            <elem2 attr="a"/>
          </elem1>
          <elem1>
            <elem2 attr="b"/>
          </elem1>
      </root>
    """;
    
var xml2 = """
      <root>
          <elem1>
            <elem2 attr="b"/>
          </elem1>
          <elem1>
            <elem2 attr="a"/>
          </elem1>
      </root>
    """;

I'm trying to write a test that would prove that they are equal.
For this I use XMLUnit
Here is the test code:
assertThat(xml1, isSimilarTo(xml2)
        .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText)));

I have also tried
assertThat(xml1, isSimilarTo(xml2)
        .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes)));

but without success.
I've found an article discussing the same problem:
https://www.insystems.nl/blog/testing-for-equality-of-xml-files-having-different-ordering-of-nested-elements/
But the solution assumes knowledge of the XML structure.
May there be another approach - reorder/sort elements in both XML files in the same way and then compare? If so, are there any libraries that do it? I've tried this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68798089/971355 but it didn't help either (seems to sort elements not at all levels)

First we talk here about elements with the same type, inside the same parent element and on the same level. Whether the sequence of these elements in an XML file is relevant depends on file's context.
If we look for example at the XML file for a DocBook document, changing the sequence of the <para> elements will definitely change the sense of the text and then the two versions are no longer equal.
On the other hand, for several configuration files in XML format, the sequence of the elements is not relevant at all.
But the sequence of the attributes for an element is irrelevant in all contexts I know about; it does not make a difference whether you sort them alphatically or by length or not at all, the interpretation is always the same:
<elem attr1="ab" attr2="ba" />

equals
<elem attr2="ba" attr1="ab" />

This means that there won't be any general solution that would be able to determine whether two XML files are semantically equal; if there is currently none for your special type of XML file, you have to create your own.

Edit based on the comment by the thread opener:

Yes, I understand. The order of some elements may be relevant and the order of the others - not. But assuming the order of all the elements isn't relevant, then it must be a general solution.

If the order of the elements does not have any semantically meaning, it would be possible to bring them to a defined order within their immediate parent element – recursively, beginning with the child elements without any further children. Also the attributes must be brought into a defined order and all redundant whitespace needs to be stripped.
Then you can use the string representation of the elements to sort them within their parent.
If you have done that for all levels up to the top, you can compare the string representation of the two XML documents for equality.
But as very few XML formats allow to re-arrange all the elements without changing the meaning and even less use cases require the comparison of XML on the document level, I doubt that there is any implementation of this in a library so that it could be used instantly.

Yes, I understand. The order of some elements may be relevant and the order of the others - not. But assuming the order of all the elements isn't relevant, then it must be a general solution.

@ka3ak – See my edit …
